# How to retrieve all contacts subscribed to a list milajet api v3

Tags: email, mailjet

I need to retrieve all contacts subscribed to a contactslist through the mailjet API.

`/contactdata` with `ContactsList: $ID` retrieve all contacts properties (firstname, name, birthday,..)

And I want thoses properties, but I also need the `Email` field.

`/contactdata` can take a `Fields` argument to list contact fields I want, `Email` is not supported :/

`/contact` with `ContactsList: $ID` give me the Email field, but not the properties

`/listrecipient` with `ContactsList: $ID` give me contactsIds, without properties nor Email.

I just want to retrieve all contacts subscribed to a list, with their properties AND their Email.

Can't I achieve that in a single Mailjet API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have all email addresses in a list with their contact properties with a single API call.

This is possible through the Mailjet WebUI, when you export the contacts list in .csv -> https://app.mailjet.com/contacts/lists

Comment: Thanks for answering.
So best practive would be to do like the MailjetWebUI, show all emails and get properties only when needed.